# Creating a new output from the combination of multiple documents coming from a stage - Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

From one of my stages I'm receiving an output which is:

```
{
  _id: "Mario",
  powers: ["Super Jump", "Cannon"],
},
{
  _id: "Superman",
  powers: ["Lasers", "Punch"],
},
{
  _id: "Batman",
  powers: ["Fang", "Blades", "Missiles"],
}
```

I want to merge all the documents into a single one such that the key would be the _id from the document and the value would be the powers. Which is something like:

```
{
  "Mario": ["Super Jump", "Cannon"],
  "Superman": ["Lasers", "Punch"],
  "Batman": ["Fang", "Blades", "Missiles"],
}
```

My attempt:

```
{
        '$project': {
            'idNameAsArray': {
                '$split': [
                    {
                        '$concatArrays': [
                            '$_id', ',', '$powers'
                        ]
                    }, ','
                ]
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '', 
            'arrayOfIdNameArrays': {
                '$push': '$idNameAsArray'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'idNameObjs': {
                '$arrayToObject': '$arrayOfIdNameArrays'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$replaceRoot': {
            'newRoot': '$idNameObjs'
        }
    }
```

As `$split` needs it to be a string, I'm pretty much confused as to what could be the best way to achieve the same within the aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below 2 stages after your pipeline stages,

- `$group` by null and construct the array of key-value pair
- `$arrayToObject` convert above converted key-value pair array of object to object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above object to root

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      items: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$powers"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$items" } }
  }
```

[Playgroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CqO75nfsM7r)